# how to retrieve firebase data in react-native and loop through each entry

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im trying to fetch data from firebase database, which im getting the data very well, but when i try to push all items received in an array, i obtain an array which i cannot iterate through like any other javascript array. here is my code:

```
var li = [];
  
  useEffect(() => {
    firebaseDB
      .database()
      .ref("collection")
      .on("value", (data) => {
        let all = data;
        
        all.forEach((element) => {
          
          li.push(element.val());
        });
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(li);
```

when i do console.log(li) , i get the li array which seems okay with the data, but when i try to do something with the array e.g. if i do console.log(li.length) , it prints 0 yet the array has multiple items in it. the problem is that my li array doesnt behave like an array. please assist me locate where the problem could be

Answer (score 1):

```
 const [arr,setArr] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
  firebaseDB
  .database()
  .ref("collection")
  .on("value", (snapshot) =>{
    let data = [];
    snapshot.forEach((child)=>{
      data.push(child.val());
    })
   setArr(data);
  });
 
},[])
```